# Generic Repository using EF

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, design-patterns, repository-pattern

I'm trying to build generic repository which I will use to get data with or without includes, add data, update data, delete data. I searched a bunch of websites, but still nothing to match my requests.

I have following code which has problem saying that I should be explicit about the type of set and it can't be generic. Do you guys have any ideas on how to build the thing I'm asking for?

```
public class BaseRepository<T>
{
    private readonly InstagramDbContext _context;

    public BaseRepository(InstagramDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public IQueryable<T> FindBy(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes)
    {
        var query = _context.Set<T>().Where(predicate);
        return includes.Aggregate(query, (current, includeProperty) => current.Include(includeProperty));
    }
}
```

Comment: This feels counter productive, you are basically re-creating EF on top of EF. You should maybe lookup the "specification pattern" that may match your use case.

Comment: Ok thanks I'll check it, but really I have to create as many repositories as many entities I have?

Comment: Your InstagramDbContext already has the repos you're building. Just like madmax said, you're reinventing the wheel.

Comment: No use from you but thanks anyway

Comment: Nobody wants to do your homework for you...

Comment: I was just asking for directions not the implementation but ok I will find or came up with one

Comment: *code which has problem saying that I should be explicit about the type of set and it can't be generic* Instead of paraphrasing, please be specific. If you have a compilation or run-time error or exception, *cut and paste the actual message*, and tell us exactly where and when it occurs.

Comment: You already have one. EF implements one. You follow an antipattern trying VERY BADLY to implement a repository pattern OVER a repository. Never seen that working. You will leak issues left and right and not even know it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to apply a constraint to the generic repo class. I do this will all my generic repositories and I never had this problem.

```
public class BaseRepository<T> where T : class
{
    // ...
}
```

Of course, if your entities have a base class that they all inherit you can replace 'class' with that base entity. I will also leave you a link from the official documentation for. Hope it helps!

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters